# How can I process a UTF8 sentence with Umlauts letter by letter?

Tags: php, split, utf-8, diacritics

I have a German sentence with "Umlaute" (ä, ö, ü, Ä, Ö, Ü, ß) and want to process it letter by letter. Let's say I want to write each word backwards.

What I have: `"Die Straße enthält viele größere Schlaglöcher"`
What I want: `"eiD eßartS tlähtne eleiv ereßörg rehcölgalhcS"`

I tried to explode the sentence to an array consisting of single words:

```
$MyText = "Die Straße enthält viele größere Schlaglöcher";
$Words = preg_split(@"/[^\wäöüÄÖÜß]/", $MyText);
```

But as soon as I try to iterate the $Words array I have a problem because it contains letters ("ä", "ö", "ü", ...) that are represented by 2 bytes (UTF8) and writing them backwards does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is like the following:

1. Convert the UTF8-String to a Unicode-String (UTF32) where every letter consists of 4 bytes
2. Split that string into 4-byte-chunks => $LetterArray
3. Do something with $LetterArray
4. Combine the changed array to a new string
5. Convert the new string back to UTF8

Here comes a code snippet how this could be done.

```
$Word = "enthält";
$Word_Unicode = mb_convert_encoding($Word, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
$Letters = str_split($Word_Unicode, 4);
$Letters = array_reverse($Letters);
$NewWord_Unicode = implode("", $Letters);
$NewWord = mb_convert_encoding($NewWord_Unicode, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32');
```

Result: `enthält => tlähtne`

Try it here: https://onlinephp.io/c/69a20

Comment: Which will fail on many cases, e.g. it original text was written by a mac: on mac an accented character uses two code points, and the accent is part of the second, which should remain after base character also after changing order. In addition many young people will add emoji, and your method will fail on such case (UTF-16 with emoji takes more then 2 bytes)

Comment: FWIW the "mac accented characters" is an issue of normalized vs denormalized forms, and can be addressed via intl's [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer) class for cases where a single codepoint exists for an accented glyph. A generalized solution for denormalized sequences is quite a bit stickier of a situation as its not simple to detect which marks are combining marks, and there's not a limit on how many combining marks can form a valid sequence.

Comment: No: UTF-16 characters can consist of [either 2 **or 4** bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_from_U+010000_to_U+10FFFF). Your code will break Emojis.

Comment: Thank you for your hint with the Emojis. That's not a problem for me. I have only regular text, but with ä, ö, ü, and so on. And for this it works perfectly. That's what the question is about.

Comment: Emojis are just one of many examples - sooner or later you'll encounter a grapheme where "_every letter consists of 2 bytes_" just isn't true in UTF-16. If you want that approach, consider using UTF-32.

Comment: You are right. I have changed the code to UTF32. Now even Smileys and other "special chars" are working perfectly. Thank you very much for this idea. 

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the `u` modifier (ungreedy) in preg_split
- Then use `mb_str_split` to slice each word into an array of letters
- Reverse the sliced word
- Then join it all together

---

```
$MyText = "Die Straße enthält viele größere Schlaglöcher";
$Words = preg_split("/[^\w]/u", $MyText);

$reversed = [];
foreach($Words as $word){
    $str_split = mb_str_split($word, 1);

    $reversed[] = implode('', array_reverse($str_split) );
}

$reversed_str = implode(' ', $reversed);

echo $reversed_str;
```

---

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php

Comment: The output of your code is the following: "enthälteiD e��artS tl��htne eleiv ere�ö�rg rehc��lgalhcS"

Comment: I tried to take a shortcut with `strrev`. You can use `mb_str_split` to get what you need.